# How to use qr-code in my cakephp project

Tags: php, cakephp, qr-code

I found a tutorial on how to generate qr codes with php [here] http://www.terragon.de/index.php?id=273 . I worked through the tutorial and now I want to use it in my cakephp project, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

I added the folder called qr-code to app/lib. Within the folder is another folder called php that contains qr_img.php which contains the essential php code.(app/Lib/qr-cpde/php/qr_img.php)

In the tutorial, I created a file called index.php that contained this code:

```
<?php
    echo "<img src='qr_img.php?d=Cara-Drye' >";
?>
```

in my code I replaced it with:

```
<?php
    echo "<img src='app/Lib/qr-code/php/qr_img.php?d=Cara-Drye' >";
?>
```

but I only gt that little image box and no qr code.

Here is my controller

```
<?php


App::import('Lib','qr-code.php.qr_img.php');


class QrCodesController extends AppController {
    //put your code here
    public $name = 'QrCodes';
    public function index(){

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You're posting a filepath as a URL. Of *course* it's not going to work. Use an absolute *URL*. Test to see if it works by pasting it into your browser's address bar.

Comment: Unfortunately, while I am sure that you know exactly what you are trying to tell me, I am still as unsure about what I am doing wrong as I was before. If you could just be a little more specific, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're referring to your *filesystem* while HTML accesses data via *URL* s. The `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag accepts URLs (i.e. "http://www.mysite.com/qr_img.php?d=Cara-Drye"). You need to try to access the file as though it's a web address that you would enter into your browser's address bar.

Comment: I see what you are saying, I am just a bit confused that I did not use an absolute url in the demo, and it worked still.

Comment: It's actually pretty good practice to set a global constant (in a config file) as an absolute value to your site root (`define('WEBROOT', "http://www.mysite.com/");`). You can then define it differently, depending on the environment you're using (development -vs- production) and not have to change any code.

Comment: It's an old thread, but the misinformation needs correcting! While it may be in some cases good practice to use a global constant to generate absolute URLs for images, it's a load of cobblers to say that inserting relative URLs into image tags won't work. As a general rule, it works fine. @Cara, the difficulty when doing so in Cake projects is that there is a lot of URL rewriting going on, so relative paths need to be thought through more carefully to make sure they're going where you think.

Answer (score 0):

once I put the source into the images folder in the webroot and changed my code to:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->image('/img/qr-code/php/qr_img.php?d=Cara-Drye');
?>
```

everything worked fine. The thing about cakephp is the built in architecture, if you are wanting to use an image, it needs to be in the image folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind using google, you can use
https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/cake2/View/Helper/QrCodeHelper.php

```
echo $this->QrCode->image($text);
```

and others like url, sms, tel, ...

Comment: The reason that I avoided that Qrcode Helper is that I was afraid it would not work in all Browsers.

Comment: you do know that jpgs (or those images) are browser independent, dont you? it is more the question if you want to use a webservice like google here.

Comment: Well I am a new programmer and am new to the Computer field all together. I am learning as I go. THanks for the info.

Comment: Link is broken, please check and update it. Thanks.

Comment: Done. IN general just look at the root repo and you will quickly find it also in latest version in default branch etc.